# Informix: Select null problem

Tags: sql, select, informix

Using Informix, I've created a tempory table which I am trying to populate from a select statement. After this, I want to do an update, to populate more fields in the tempory table.

So I'm doing something like;

```
create temp table _results (group_ser int, item_ser int, restype char(4));

insert into _results (group_ser, item_ser)
select 
      group_ser, item_ser, null
from
      sometable
```

But you can't select null.

For example;

```
select first 1 current from systables
```

works but

```
select first 1 null from systables
```

fails!

(Don't get me started on why I can't just do a SQL Server like "select current" with no table specified!)

Comment: FYI - I hate informix!

Comment: You don't have to love it, but you'd better understand it. RDBMs allow a user to obtain all the relevant information from a query (DESCRIBE). This includes obtaining the number and types of the columns in the result set, based on a query. That's what allows completely dynamic SQL (the application can adapt itself to a query written on the fly by the user).

The problem with your query is that NULL is typeless by definition. So your query is not allowed. I'd be interested to know how other RDBMs deal with that... Probably they set a default type...
Just cast your NULL and it works.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Bridge/4578/faq.html) says the reason you can't do that is because "NULL" doesn't have a type.  So, the workaround is to create a sproc that simply returns NULL in the type you want.

That sounds like a pretty bad solution to me though.  Maybe you could create a variable in your script, set it to null, then select that variable instead?  Something like this:

```
DEFINE dummy INT;
LET dummy = NULL;

SELECT group_ser, item_ser, dummy
FROM sometable
```

Comment: +1 +Answer. Haven't tried it, but your answer make perfect sense.

Comment: Note that the FAQ in question is dated 1998.  Some things have changed since then.

Answer (score 24):

You don't have to write a stored procedure; you simply have to tell IDS what type the NULL is.  Assuming you are not using IDS 7.31 (which does not support any cast notation), you can write:

```
SELECT NULL::INTEGER FROM dual;

SELECT CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) FROM dual;
```

And, if you don't have `dual` as a table (you probably don't), you can do one of a few things:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dual FOR sysmaster:"informix".sysdual;
```

The 'sysdual' table was added relatively recently (IDS 11.10, IIRC), so if you are using an older version, it won't exist.  The following works with any version of IDS - it's what I use.

```
-- @(#)$Id: dual.sql,v 2.1 2004/11/01 18:16:32 jleffler Exp $
-- Create table DUAL - structurally equivalent to Oracle's similarly named table.
-- It contains one row of data.

CREATE TABLE dual
(
    dummy CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'x' NOT NULL CHECK (dummy = 'x') PRIMARY KEY
) EXTENT SIZE 8 NEXT SIZE 8;
INSERT INTO dual VALUES('x');

REVOKE ALL ON dual FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON dual TO PUBLIC;
```

Idiomatically, if you are going to SELECT from Systables to get a single row, you should include '`WHERE tabid = 1`'; this is the entry for Systables itself, and if it is missing, the fact that your SELECT statement does return any data is the least of your troubles.  (I've never seen that as an error, though.)

Comment: Just using NULL::INTEGER instead of NULL is the simplest, this is better than creating procedure or other examples given in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT group_ser, item_ser, replace(null,null) as my_null_column
FROM sometable
```

or you can use `nvl(null,null)` to return a null for your select statement.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason to go for an actual table? I have been using

```
select blah from table(set{1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select blah from table(set{1})
```

is nice when you are using 10.x database. This statement doesn't touch database. The amount of read/write operations is equal to 0,

but

when you're using 11.x it will cost you at least 4500 buffer reads because this version of Informix creates this table in memory and executes query against it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date(null) from table;
```

This works when I want to get a date with null value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression (''+1) on the SELECT list, instead of null keyword. It evaluates to NULL value of type DECIMAL(2,0).

This (''+1.0001) evaluates to DECIMAL(16,4). And so on.

If you want DATE type use DATE(''+1) to get null value of type DATE.

(''+1)||' ' evaluates to an empty string of type VARCHAR(1).

To obtain NULL value of type VARCHAR(1) use this expression:
DATE(''+1)||' '

Works in 9.x and 11.x.