# How to make a cell blank in a row from a query result?

Tags: sql, informix

I have a query as below:

```
SELECT 
     cc.chain_desc as chain_desc 
    ,cc.chain_id as chain_id 
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) as TranCount
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC') 
GROUP BY cc.chain_desc, cc.chain_id 


UNION 

SELECT 
    'TOTAL'
    ,0
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) 
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC')
```

The above query when executed reurns the below result:

[image]

I need the result to be displayed as below:

[image]

The column "Chain_Id" is of "integer" type, how can I make that blank?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Informix you can use `NULL` in the projection list, but the column must have a type. Since in Informix `NULL` does not have a type, you need to use a `CAST`.

```
SELECT NULL::INTEGER AS id FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;

SELECT CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) AS id FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;
```

You can check the answers to this other question ([Informix: Select null problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665944/informix-select-null-problem)).

You can check the IBM Knowledge Center ([NULL Keyword](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0192.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

you can simply select null

```
 .....

 UNION 

SELECT 
    'TOTAL'
    , NULL::INTEGER
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) 
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN chain_desc as cc 
ON l.chain_id = cc.chain_id 
WHERE 
t.loc_country = 'U' 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156966,166203) 
AND t.trans_date >= '2016-10-01 00:00' 
and t.trans_date < '2016-10-31 00:00'
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC')
```

because null is not a type you could try  add  above the first query

```
DEFINE test INT;
LET test = NULL;


......

SELECT 
    'TOTAL'
    , test
    ,COUNT(distinct t.trans_id) 
    .....
```

Or like suggusted by @Jonathan Leffler use `NULL::INTEGER`  or `CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)`

Comment: If I select NULL, I'm getting an error. I'm using SQL Workbench to test the queries.

Comment: I habe update the asnwer .. hope is clear and useful

Comment: @Newbee: In Informix, you need to specify the type of null — e.g. `NULL::INTEGER` — rather than use just plain `NULL`, which could be any type.  You can also use `CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)` if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to convert to `NULL`:

```
    (case when cc.chain_id <> 0 then cc.chain_id end) as chain_id
```

Another is to convert everything to a string:

```
    (case when cc.chain_id <> 0 then cast(cc.chain_id as varchar(255)) else '' end) as chain_id
```